# How to think in a discrete math mindset?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

This problem has stumped me:

> Suppose we have $k$ colors (call them $1, 2, \dots, k$), and let $n = C_1 + C_2 + \dots + C_k$, where we make no assumption about the $C_i$ except that they are integers summing to $n$. We have $n$ objects to paint with the $k$ colors, and each object must be painted a solid color. Prove that for some $1 \leq i \leq k$, we must paint at least $C_i$ objects with color $i$.
>
> Hint: by contradiction—what if we do not paint at least $C_i$ objects with color $i$, for every $1 \leq i \leq k$?

I get that it is most likely a pigeonhole principle problem but I do not understand what I have to prove. That there will be an unpainted object or two colors will be on the same object, and what the math behind that would be.

Is there any general tips for discrete math to get in the right state of mind to attack these problems?

Comment: General tips which apply to more than just discrete math: 

1. Simplify the problem. If you can solve a simpler version of the problem, you may gain insights into the original problem.

2. As your hint says, consider the contrary. If you want to show some proposition is true, what would it take for that propositition to be false? What is wrong with the universe in which that proposition is false?

Comment: You need to try to reread and better understand what the problem is talking about.  Imagine if you will... a bag of M&Ms... little candies who are colored one of a few types of colors.  Suppose the bag hasn't been opened yet but we can feel through the packaging and can count how many there are and that there are $15$ candies in the bag (*or are otherwise assured that there are $15$ candies in the bag, $n$ in general*).  Now... I can come up with some numbers, $C_1,C_2,\dots$ as a rough guess as to what the color-spread of the candies will be like... say, $4$ blue, $3$ brown, $3$ red, etc...

Comment: The question is asking us to prove that, assuming my choices of numbers for the colors adds up to $15$... that is, assuming $C_1+C_2+\dots+C_k=n$... that I will be guaranteed a color such that I find at least that many candies of that color after opening the bag

Comment: "*I get it is most likely a pigeon hole principle problem*"  Yes, this is a form of the generalized pigeonhole principle, and the bound could actually have been tighter... but the hint should lead you to a solid conclusion... what if we only found *three* blue, *two* brown candies etc... less than what we were hoping to find in every case... How many candies were actually in the bag if that were so?  Could we have actually had the full $n$ candies we were told were in the bag?

Comment: "*That there will be an unpainted object or two colors will be on the same object*"  No, The problem statement told us clearly that each object will be painted exactly one color with the phrase "*each object must be painted a solid color.*"  You are tasked with proving that our guess for quantity of each color, whatever it happened to be, (*assuming such a guess were logical and had color-counts adding up to $n$*) will have us be correct in at least one color that said color has at least as many as we guessed.

Comment: @JMoravitz I guess I get the concept behind the question better now but I still don't know where to start mathwise. Would my proof by contradiction be proving that exactly one object is associated with exactly one color?

Comment: Every object has exactly one color.  That is already known.  That was given in the problem statement.  Again... read the hint.  If we had *fewer* than $C_1$ objects of the first color and *fewer* than $C_2$ objects of the second color... etc...  then can you show that there are *fewer* than $n$ objects in total?  For example... if $n=10$ and $k=2$, we're only dealing with two colors... supposing that $C_1=C_2=5$, is it possible for us to have ten objects, at most four of which are of the first color and at most four of which are the second?

Comment: $4+4$ is only $8$... not $10$, and there could have been even fewer than that.  Now... that is only one example of $n,k,C_1,\dots$.  However, however we phrase it it needs to be done very generally so it covers the multitude of infinitely many other possibilities as well.

Comment: @JMoravitz okay that makes a bit more sense I was assuming colors were unique in themselves not the objects being unique and the colors being on more than one object. I guess the only problem I have with this is that I do not understand the consequence of there being a discontinuity in the sequence of objects much less how to prove it mathematically. Apologies if these are easy questions this is the first couple weeks of discrete and I am still trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: If I have ten objects, each object colored either red or blue... can I guarantee that there will be at least five red objects or at least five blue objects?  Yes, because otherwise we would have at most four red and at most four blue.  Letting $r$ be the actual number of red objects and $b$ the actual number of blue, we would have had $10 = r+b\leq 4+b\leq 4+4 = 8$ which would say that $10\leq 8$ which we know to be false, a contradiction.  Now, generalize this

Answer (score 0):

The main idea, is than an amount greater than $n-k$ couldn't have all $C_i$ lowered by 1. $n-k$ you can take 1 away from each of the $k$ subsets, adding 1 forces at least 1 of the $C_i$ to have greater than or equal to it's amount.